# I need help with finding a library or tutorial to parallel optimize given a black box function, assuming it's convex

Tags: python, convex-optimization

I have a black box function to optimize with respect to 1-D input,$\beta$, and I also have other inputs, which I don't need to optimize, say (x,y). So, I need to optimize f($\beta$, x,y) over $\beta$. Now, I have a bunch of data points {$(x_n,y_n)$}, n = 1,2,...,N. So, if I use sklearn for example, I have to iterate over each $(x_n,y_n)$ to get $b_n^*$. It gets very computationally slow. I am wondering if there is any library or tutorial to get {$b_n^*$}, at once, given all {$(x_n,y_n)$} so I can avoid iterations.

Comment: Depending on how close the $(x_i, y_i)$ are to each other and how steeply $f$ changes with respect to argument ("close" and "not very fast" being what you are hoping), you could perhaps use an optimization method that allows you to "hot start" it for each $n$ using the solution for $n-1$ (or information gleaned from that solution, such as a neighborhood or bounds). You would still have to solve a problem for each $n,$, but the hot starts might make the computation time acceptable.

Comment: Is it a smooth function?